# An error occurred when performing a file operation read on file D:\wwwroot\arises2s\www\s2s\assets\config_Literacy.xml

Tags: iis, coldfusion

Can any body help me out why I am getting this error I am running a website which is written in coldfusion and running on IIS server there are some other XML files which are running perfectly  this error is occurring intermittently please advice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you seeing that error? From a generated page? The Windows event log?

Answer (score 2):

That error implies the file your trying to open isn't there.

If you supply more of the error page your seeing or check your application log you may see this

The cause of this exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\wwwroot\arises2s\www\s2s\assets\config_Literacy.xml

Give us the java.io. error your seeing.